# 401.2 after moving to IIS7

Tags: authentication, iis-7, http-status-code-401

We have a website that is supposed to be fully open an available to everyone.  It hosts several web services.  It is configured for anonymous authentication.  I am migrating it from an IIS 6 server to an IIS7 server (with a new url, both sites should be active during the transition).  I am getting a 401.2 error trying to access the site on the new server.  How is this possible, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I just found out this only affects asmx files.  If I try to load page.asmx, I get a 401.2 error, regardless of whether page.asmx even exists!  If I try to load any other file, I get the file if it exists, or I get a 404 if it does not.

Comment: Try Fiddler to check whether the page is redirecting elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can set anonymous authentication on and must check out the deny rule in .net authorization part to be sure your application has access to all user.
If you are having any other authentication then also it must work you can check out your error in details in the Log folder.